# How to create multiple TCP connections within 1 gRPC stream

Tags: c++, grpc

I'm using gRPC stream to transfer data from server to client, and am suffering low throughput. One thing specific to my case is: my client only sends control messages(eg, start, pause, resume), and server streams messages back till the end.

One thing I think could be useful is parallelization, and make full utilization of the b/w.
But one consideration is: my messages sent is ordered, which means if I open multiple multiple gRPC streams, I don't have a way to tell their order.

My question is: is there a way in gRPC to open multiple TCP connections?

Comment: Why would multiple TCP connections improve throughput?  The total bandwidth available should be the same regardless of how many TCP connections are sharing it.

Comment: You can create multiple connections to the same backend from one client with gRPC, but there is no way to have one stream share the connections.

Comment: Actually, multiple gRPC streams with the same argument shares one single TCP connection. And we could achieve to leverage multiple TCP connections by :
```grpc::ChannelArguments args; args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_USE_LOCAL_SUBCHANNEL_POOL, 1);```

Comment: Yes, total b/w is the same, but each stream will have its own network stack and can be transferred seperately.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner the b/w for one single TCP connection is only 10MBps, so I am thinking to use multiple TCP connections (maybe multiple grpc stub sharing one TCP connections?) to improve total throughput. Do you think it workable?

Comment: @Dentiny a TCP connection is only a method for placing data into packets.  If you're getting 10MBps with a single TCP connection, then two simultaneous TCP connections will likely get 5MBps each at best (actually slightly less, since there is some per-connection overhead), and so on.  The exception might be if the bottleneck is on the server-side, and you can usefully have the client connect to multiple servers at once.  E.g. if each server can serve up only 10MBps but the client's connection can receive >10MBps, then downloading from multiple servers at once might help.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I used `iperf` to test the throughput for multiple TCP connections, and I actually get 100MBps for 10 conns. jw, do we have a way to utilize multiple TCP connections? I feel confused about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71813539/how-to-create-multiple-tcp-connections-in-grpc

Comment: @Dentiny perhaps the server has implemented a per-connection bandwidth cap then; if that is the case, then probably the easiest thing to do would be to increase (or remove) the bandwidth-cap from the server.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner It's a kubernetes pod, I run `iperf` directly in the pod. I don't think I could (or say I don't know) how to resolve this issue. :(