# How to create multiple TCP connections in grpc

Tags: c++, tcp, grpc, channel, stub

context: I have an application which retrieves data from service. `iperf` shows download throughout for one single TCP connections is only 20MBps, but the requirement is 100MBps.

I tried `iperf` with 10 TCP connections (`iperf -c <IP port> -P 10`), and it shows the bandwidth could be 100MBps. So I want to use multiple TCP connections.

We use grpc to transfer data. From some google and stackoverflow (like https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/21332), I know

- grpc leverages HTTP/2, which natively supports IO multiplexing, but the limitation for my application is TCP b/w, so have to use multiple TCP connections
- `channel` is the abstraction which represents TCP connection
- `stub` is for client use. So it should be possible to have multiple stubs sharing one single `channel`

My way of doing it is

```
  grpc::ChannelArguments args;
  args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_USE_LOCAL_SUBCHANNEL_POOL, 1);
  std::shared_ptr<Channel> channel(grpc::CreateCustomChannel(
      ip_port, grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials(), args));
  stub_ = NewStub(channel);
```

But from `ss`, I only see a few TCP connections created.

```
> ss -antp | grep 443 | wc -l
3
```

And not all of them are from my program.

My question is: how to create multiple TCP connection in grpc in C++?

Answer (score 0):

This goes more to the desire behind the question, which is achieving 100 MB/s of TCP throughput.  One of the many limits to the performance of a TCP connection is:

Throughput <= WindowSize / RoundTripTime

If you see increased performance in iperf with parallel connections, it is a strong indication your single-stream performance is "window limited."  If you control or influence both ends of the connection (being able to run iperf suggests that is the case) you can increase the limits to the TCP window size and perhaps get your single-stream throughput to where you want it.

The most likely sysctls you would want to tune would be:
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem

You need to tune on both sides.

The "best" thing to do is to take the RoundTripTime (say measured via ping) and multiply that (in units of seconds) by the desired bandwidth.  That will be how much TCP window you need.  To get that with Linux, make certain the third value of each of those two sysctls is at least twice that value.

Or you can just wing it and make those third values ten times what they are now.  Why ten?  Because you said you got the desired throughput with ten parallel streams, which suggests ten times the aggregate TCP Window got you what you wanted.